# Is there a way to run tests on a git branch while working on another one?

Tags: git, tdd

I have a large tests suite, that needs to be run before I push my changes back to the repo used by CI. Ideally I would like to use the following workflow:

- Create branch to develop feature or correct bug;
- Develop the feature in this branch using TDD, but running only the most obviously related tests;
- After finished developing, run the whole test suite;
- While I'm running the whole test suite (20 minutes), I would like to begin another feature in another branch.

If I do a git checkout, my whole working copy is changed to that branch, so I can't run my tests. Maybe I should use 2 working copies, but I would prefer a more elegant solution.

edit: typo

Comment: Just a follow-up: since I posted this question I've started using cloud CI. Now testing everything is as easy as `git push origin my_branch`

Comment: I'm interested in this capability, specifically for the case where I am trying out experiments, and I'm targeting hardware connected to my system. Pushing an experiment doesn't help, since the CI server doesn't have this hardware.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to make a second working copy for this; Consider that your next feature to implement may not be a new branch but instead uses an existing branch or a branch based on a different branch (anything that means you would be checking out code that reverts your last feature implementation during the test run).

You could make a script to handle all of it -- perhaps you finish development of the current feature, then run the "buildandtesteverything {featurebranchname}" script.  Script will move up to the directory that contains the root of your git repository, clones the repository into a temporary folder (checking out the named branch), and then executes your tests and cleans up after itself.

Comment: you just invented containers